# Why is pooling used with Bidirectional LSTM for Text classification problems (NLP)?

Tags: neural-networks, python, natural-language, lstm, k-nearest-neighbour

As per my understanding, we use pooling with CNN to downsize matrix dimension which will increase computational efficiency of model and will decrease location sensitivity of model.

However, some people are using pooling concept with LSTM to solve text classification problem (NLP). And I am failing to understand utility of using pooling concept with LSTM.

I know, reducing dimensions will give computational efficiency to LSTM model, but is their any other benefit in using pooling.

for referance check this kaggle code --> https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/emotion-classification-using-deep-learning